# TableView in TableViewCell with RxSwift Binding

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to bind a tableview in a tableview cell to an observable. The first tableview works perfect, but the problem is that the second tableview inside the cell is not displayed even though it gets the data.

I have 2 functions: function: "populateCustomCategorys" is for the main table view and the function "populateDetailCustomCategory" is for the tableview inside the cell.

Heres my code:

//MARK: Custom TableView
    private func populateCustomCategorys() {
        let observableItems = viewModel.getCustomCleaningPlanData().asObservable()
        observableItems.bind(to: customTableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "dailyCustomCell", cellType: DailyCustomTableViewCell.self)) { (row, element, cell) in
            cell.titleLabel.text = element.categoryName

```
    }.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
}

//MARK: Custom Detail Table View
private func populateDetailCustomCategorys() {
    let cell = customTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dailyCustomCell") as! DailyCustomTableViewCell

    observableItems.bind(to: cell.DetailTableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "dailyDetailCustomCell", cellType: DailyCustomDetailTableViewCell.self)) { (row, element, cell) in
        //print(cell.titleLabel)
        //cell.titleLabel.text = element.owner.title
        //cell.checkmarcButton.isSelected = element.owner.status
        cell.config(title: element.owner.title ?? "Temp", check: element.owner.status)

       print("/////////// \(element)")
       // print()
    }.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
}[enter image description here][1]
```